# Github X-RateLimit-Remaining is not zero and "limit exceeded" error is thrown

Tags: python, github, python-requests, github-api

I am experiencing this issue when in response headers I see X-RateLimit-Remaining is set to a value other than zero, but an exception is raised with  "Max retries exceeded (Caused by ResponseError('too many 403 error responses'))"